# Nokogiri, find XML node with multiple attributes and change text

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to change a indl file. The indl file is a file created by Adobe Indesign to keep the structure of a document, and is basically an XML. I want to use Nokogiri to find some selected XML nodes and replace the text with my text, saving then the xml to another file.

The XML of course is strange: i find some document to retrieve HTML tag with Nokogiri changing text but I don't know How I can manage a piece of XML like this:

```
<cflo>
<txsr prst="o_u5084" crst="o_u5085" trak="D_10">
    <pcnt>c_tEST</pcnt>
</txsr>
<txsr prst="o_u5086" crst="o_u5c" trak="D_20">
 <pcnt>c_Titolo titolo titolo</pcnt>
</txsr>
<cflo>
```

Basically I need to look for a combination of `prst` and `crst` attribute and replace the content inside the `pcnt` node.

I try with this

```
@doc.xpath("//txsr[prst='o_u5086' and crst='o_u5085']")
```

but I don't know how I can change ther text inside the `pcnt` node.

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/
I also found ox is 5 times faster than nokogiri while reading a large xml.
Plus I have a wrapper written which simply allow you to search through large xml using ox, allows you to iterate with specified element.
https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431

Comment: Your XML isn't valid as there isn't a closing tag.Is this in the actual XML? That can confuse parsers, making them return invalid results.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's not the correct XPath. The correct XPath will look like this:

   ```
   @doc.xpath("//txsr[@prst='o_u5086'][@crst='o_u5085']")
   ```
2. You should just take the first node from a set and use the `inner_html=` method to replace the text value.

Full code may be found here: https://gist.github.com/kaineer/7673698

Comment: MMh... the selector is working. I retrieve the content of the element now but I can't change it. Undefined method inner_html :(

Comment: Seems to me, you've lost part of your output.
When I've modified xpath to yours, I've got "undefined method `inner_html=' for nil:NilClass".
And it is obvious. You do not get nodes from XML DOM, because of wrong xpath and you can not modify content of nodes you did not get.

Let me tell you why your xpath was wrong. It does not test attributes' values, because you need @ sign to do so.
Using 'and' instead of multiply brackets, proved itself right, though :)
So, @doc.xpath("//txsr[@prst='o_u5086' and @crst='o_u5085']") would work too.

Comment: Again, if you will not add '/pcnt' at the tail of your xpath, you'll need more code to get down to pcnt node.